# Java: Help concerning runnable

Tags: java, android, runnable

I'm newbe in Java programming and I want to know what the following code do:
did it execute the setUp function every 1000 milllisecond without stop ?

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setUp();
            }
            }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, it will run it with a 1000ms delay.

Also, that looks like android ;) If you want to get a call every second use a TimerTask instead. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Answer (score 1):

No, it will run only once, after 1000 ms. As specified in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29):

> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run
>   after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run
>   on the thread to which this handler is attached.

Answer (score 0):

JavaDoc of [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) is as follow so it will execute after `1000ms`

> public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)
>   Since: API Level 1
>
> Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.
>   Parameters
>
> r  The Runnable that will be executed.
>
> delayMillis    The delay (in milliseconds) until the Runnable will be executed.